Designing a flat-phase DFT / DTFT window
Problem
I have a sampled time domain record of a signal with unknown, but constant frequency and amplitude, superimposed on a roughly white-noise background in the relevant frequency range.
I now want to extract the phase of the signal from the time record using a DFT.
For now, the background noise density is low enough that I do not need to care about SNR-reducing effects from high-NENBW windows, so all reasonable windows are admissible.
For determining the signal amplitude, there exist predesigned "flattop" windows to decrease the maximum-amplitude dependence on the signal detuning from the bin-center.
Thus, even if my signal has a frequency between two bins, I can estimate it fairly accurately by taking the DFT (+ necessary normalization) of the flattop-windowed signal.
I was not able to find any equivalent windows minimizing the phase dependence on the signal detuning. So I would like to know how to find preexisting windows of that sort, or how to design them. Such a window would be helpful in all contexts where phase information is relevant.

Previous work/stuff I tried/thought about

There may be some gain by using complex-valued windows
The sum two windows of type $A_{\mathrm{ref}}\sin(2\pi f_{\mathrm{ref}} x)$, where $x \in [0,1]$ can be optimized such that the phase is independent of the detuning at least locally around the bin center, e.g. $w(x) = \sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi x/2.925)$ (see image below for 10000 samples).
However, the flat section is much thinner than a bin.
When detuning by $\pm f_{BW}/2$, all common windows sweep over 180° of phase.
Is this potentially a mathematical fact?
In fact, windows which are sums of sinewaves which fit periodically in the window (like Hann & Hamming), and which have a main lobe with a width of $2k$ bins continuously sweep over $k \cdot 180°$ inside of $[f_{\mathrm{signal}} - kf_{BW}, f_{\mathrm{signal}} + kf_{BW}]$. At all roots of the spectral response function, the phase jumps by 180°. This makes sense, considering the spectral response is continuous, so at any root, it passes straight through the origin, leading to the 180° phase shift.
In general, if I want a window that's locally phase-flat and amplitude-flat at the bin center, then for N samples and a window $w_n, n\in \{0,\dots,N-1\}
$,
$$0 = \partial_f \,\mathrm{DFT}_n[w_n](f) \vert_{f=0} = \left( \partial_f\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-\frac{2\pi i f n}{N}} w_n \right)\Bigg|_{f=0}
\propto\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} n e^{-\frac{2\pi i 0 n}{N}} w_n = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} n w_n$$
which is doable, but also possibly only works locally.


By "spectral response" of a window, I mean the DTFTs of the window itself, so the resulting spectrum that any signal will produce.
E.g. the orange plot here
